# FireStore draws Charts overlapping display

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I want to draw a chart, fill the chart with data from firestore, but it overlaps as shown in the picture
I use the library https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts to create charts, using swift.. Sorry for the unclear description

[image]

What I want is to populate the Charts in chronological order, this is my FireStore
[image]

I am just new at this so if anyone can help me with this it would be great.

```
func LiveChart() {
        db.collection("Admin").document("AiSmartRobot").collection("AiDailyProfit").addSnapshotListener({ [self] (querySnapShot, error) in
            
            for document in querySnapShot!.documents{
                
                if let quantity = document.data()["quantity"] as? Double{
                    if let datetime = document.data()["date"] as? String{
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        let barChartView = BarChartView(frame: live.bounds)
                        barChartView.delegate = self
                        barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
                        
                        let xValues = [datetime]
                        barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: xValues)
                        self.live.addSubview(barChartView)
                        var values = [BarChartDataEntry]()
                        let numbers : [Double] = [quantity]
                        for i in 0..<numbers.count {
                            let value = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: numbers[i])
                            values.append(value)
                        }
                        let ds = BarChartDataSet(values: values, label: "")
                        let data = BarChartData(dataSets: [ds])
                        ds.valueColors = [UIColor(red: 57.0/255.0, green: 176.0/255.0, blue: 158.0/255.0, alpha: 1)]
                        barChartView.data = data
                        barChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
                        barChartView.animate(yAxisDuration: 2)
                        barChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Firestore does not draw any charts. It's a NoSQL database. Please edit the question and provide more information about your problem.

Comment: I want to draw a chart, fill the chart with data from firestore

Comment: In what language? What library you want to draw a chart? No one knows that. (except Frank)

Comment: `let barChartView = BarChartView(frame: live.bounds)`, without knowing the library you use this must be wrong since you are create a new `BarChartView` for each row of data you receive from Firebase. Separate the code from where you receive your data from the code where you create the chart.

Comment: I use the library https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts to create charts, using swift.. Sorry for the unclear description

Comment: Can you give me an example code if I need to do it to achieve my idea?